# Do migrated questions always display Migrated from...?

Tags: support, migration

I think about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863054/how-to-parse-json-data-to-mootools-javascript) question. Because the user seems to not exist on Stackoverflow, I concluded it must have been migrated. But should a automatic "migrated from" message be there?

Or the fact that the user is bot clickable has to do with something else?

Comment: The user could have deleted their account or been deleted by a moderator...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, ok. That means that questions from a deleted account are not deleted, didn't know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The greyed out avatar and userid you see means one thing: there is no active account associated to the post. That can happen, as you say, if a question is migrated and the user does not yet have an active account on the target site.

It does however also happen for deleted accounts, which as a result will see the posts anonymized. And that would seem to be the most likely explanation here. It is not the case that user deletion means all content will go with them.

Comment: Thank you Bart, and "just for the record": if a question is migrated it should automatically have the "migrated from" message(?)

Comment: Yes @Sergio. AFAIK that should always appear

Comment: @Bart It will always appear unless a moderator explicitly clears migration history on a question. This is rare though.

Comment: Ah thanks @AnnaLear, learned something  new.

Comment: I learned too, thank you both.

Comment: @AnnaLear I think we're giving mods to much power if they can clear question _history_

Comment: @Cole Why would that be a bad thing to allow them to do? There are cases where it definitely makes sense, although rare like Anna said. Besides, mods have lots of power, the only problem comes when they abuse it. And there are ways of handling that.

Comment: @CodyGray ah I see you didn't see my sarcasm. I forgot a smiley :/